# Error: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new ngTableParams')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I am trying to use ng-table but stuck with ngTableParams. I keep getting the

```
[Error] Error: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new ngTableParams')
```

error, no matter what things I try.

The current code looks like

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,
    count: 200,
    sorting: {
        name: 'asc'
    }
}, {
    groupBy: 'area',
    total: TheData.length,
    getData: function($defer, params) {
        // use build-in angular filter
        var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(TheData, params.orderBy()) : TheData;
        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }
});
```

The app and controller are invoked with ngTable and ngTableParams:

```
angular.module('MegaList', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngTable']);
angular.module('MegaList').controller('DisplayMegaList', ['$scope', 'ngTableParams', function($scope, $http, ngTableParams) {
    ...
}
```

I think I've already tried all the ways to compose `'ngTable'`, `'ngTableParams'` and `ngTableParams` keywords together, but it still just doesn't work.

What should I try then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are missing parameter. All have to matched as well

```
angular.module('MegaList')
       .controller('DisplayMegaList', ['$scope', '$http', 'ngTableParams', function($scope, $http, ngTableParams)
```

Comment: In fact, the order of dependencies matters. It must match the arguments. i.e. `['$scope', 'ngTableParams', function($scope, ngTableParams, $http) {}]`

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you create controller on a different module. Try to use `MegaList.controller(...)` instead of `FloristList.controller(...)`.

Comment: It's not the case, I just mistyped the code. The module is all the same. In description section of this question, I rewrote code a little to avoid any unnecessary variables, so now it's clear that everything happens within one module.

Comment: It looks like now you have unequal number of parameters. try: `angular.module('MegaList').controller('DisplayMegaList', ['$scope', '$http', 'ngTableParams', function($scope, $http, ngTableParams)`

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and just copying the `beforeEach` from this sample helped me:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
  // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
  $controller = _$controller_;
}));
```